How can I insert a formula into a newly created cell?
I'm trying to have a formula insert itself automatically into a newly created cell. I'm using the following Macro in excel to essentially fill the workbook in from the top line.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo enditall
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Cells.Column = 8 Then
        If Target.Cells.Row = 7 Then
            N = Target.Cells.Row
            If Range("H" & 7).Value <> "" Then
             Range("H7").EntireRow.Insert
             Range("A7").Select
             End If
        End If
    End If
    
enditall:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

In the newly created row I want for the new I7 cell to have a formula automatically applied to it. Can I add something into the macro to automatically apply the formula?
I'm very new to all of this so thank you for your help!
I've tried to use the fill option and setting it up as a table, but that breaks the rest of the document.


Using AutoFill to copy over the formula from cell I8 to cell I7

Microsoft documentation:

Range.AutoFill method (Excel)

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo enditall
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = "$H$7" Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Target.EntireRow.Insert
            Me.Range("I8").AutoFill Destination:=Me.Range("I7:I8"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    End If
enditall:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

